# Text doesn't drop down a line, overflow:hidden, jScrollpane

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane ( jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com ) to display a series of images, alongside a div horizontally. I managed to make the series of images work, but when I create the div, the content inside it either (a) goes outside the div, or (b) when I label it overflow:hidden, it inherits the scrolling effect, and hence doesn't go down a line.

What I would like to do is to make the text in my div act like normal text, and drop down a line when it appraoches the width of the container.

Here's my code,

```
<div class="scroll-pane">                                                                           
    <ul>
        <li ><img src="img/portfolio1.gif" /> <span></span></li>
        <li ><img src="img/portfolio2.gif"/> <span></span></li>
        <li ><img src="img/portfolio3.gif"/> <span></span></li>
        <li>
            <div class="info">
                <h2>Modern Palace Resident</h2>
                <p>This is going to describe the apartment a little bit, including design philosophy, themes for the apartments, and why you chose to do it this way. This can excite them about the apartment, which will lead them to buy. You can leave a link <a href="apt.php">here</a> as well.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant SCSS

```
.scroll-pane{
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;

    ul {
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        li{
            float:left;
            .info{
                float:left;
                width:300px;
                height:420px;
                background-color:gray;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            img{
                height:420px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant part is

```
.info{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:420px;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

What would I need to edit here, so that the `h2`, and `p` respect the `.info` container?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the CSS is even working in the above syntax. I had to change it around to get it to work in a fiddle in the first place like this:

```
.scroll-pane{
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.scroll-pane ul{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.scroll-pane ul li{
    float:left;
}

.scroll-pane ul li img{
    height:420px;
}

.info{
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    width:300px;
    height:420px;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Anyhow, the reason your text is not wrapping is because in your `.scroll-pane` style you have set `white-space:nowrap;`, which is inherited by your container.

To make the info text wrap add `white-space:normal;` to `.info`.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ts4uw/)

As I had to manually fix the CSS to work in the first place within the fiddle, feel free to let me know if something doesn't look right or add your own fiddle and post the link and I look at it.

Regardless though, the wrapping should be working ones you add `white-space:normal;` to the `.info` style

Comment: Aand the white-space fixed it! Thanks Francois. By the way, the CSS is styled that way thanks to SASS (www.sass-lang.com). It's been very effective for time savings for me